# Google Cloud: GCE incoming traffic from 1e100.net showing up in iptables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

While not a huge concern I'm a bit curious as to why this is happening on Google Compute Engine. I have a VM that is firewalled (using Google Cloud's firewall) to not accept any traffic from the outside, it can only be reached over ssh by a bastian host.

The machine is also running iptables which denies all incoming traffic (except port 22, and established/related).

> iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=74.125.133.95 DST=10.XXX.XXX.X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=26920 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
>
> iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=74.125.133.95 DST=10.XXX.XXX.X LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=26920 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0

I understand why iptables is logging this, my iptables config is basically:

```
*filter

#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
#  Accept all established inbound connections
INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
#  Allow SSH connections from bastian network (not between instances)
INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -s 10.XXX.XX.XXX/24 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow from google metadata
INPUT -p tcp -s 169.254.169.254/32 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

#  Log iptables denied calls
INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

#  Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
INPUT -j DROP
FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

And my question is - why is Google Compute Engine (1e100.net) on GCE trying to communicate over a none established connection? `netstat` shows no process listening on those destination ports.

All commands appear to work, so it doesn't disturb the actual communication.

I'm guessing it's trying to talk to some service on the Compute Engine VM (it's based on Googles Debian Image), but that must be quickly spinning up the listener since I can't find any reference to it in netstat.

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR**: 1e100.net is a Google-owned domain name used to identify the servers in their network.

You can read more about this domain in [What is 1e100.net?](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en).

So, don't worry about this queries, this is just an auto discovery feature implemented on Google Cloud Platform.